# Implementing NSURLConnectionDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I'm new to the Network service.
I'm trying to implement this protocole and I have some question :

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"connection didReceiveResponse");
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"connection didReceiveData");
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse
{
    // Retourne nil pour indiquer qu'il n'est pas nécessaire de stocker les réponses en cache pour cette connexion
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    // Si on a reçu des données, on peut parser
    if(self.responseData.length > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading lenght data = %i", self.responseData.length);
        NSError **parseError = nil;

        self.myDictionnaryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:parseError];

        if(parseError != nil)
            NSLog(@"Erreur lors du parse des données");
    }

    self.finished = YES;

}

// Appelé s'il y a une erreur related to the URL connection handling / server response.
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.finished = YES;
    NSLog(@"connection didFailWithError");
}
```

**but I have a problem : The first redirect doesn't works ..**

```
-(IBAction)submitForm:(id)sender
 {
 self.finished = NO;


// On met l'url avec les variables sous forme de chaine de caractere
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&pwd=%@&regid=%@&platform=%@&version=%@",self.identifying,self.password,token,platform,systemVersion];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_LOGIN_API]] autorelease];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; // de type post
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

while(!self.finished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

This is my connection. When I redirect the first time, all the object in my dictionary are null, when I re-try it, it's ok ..
 It seems the method are called after the request

EDIT : It works if I add something like :

```
while(!self.finished) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
```

and

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
NSError **parseError = nil;
self.myDictionnaryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:parseError];

if(parseError != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Erreur lors du parse des données");
}

self.finished = YES;
}
```

Comment: Give details of the redirect

Comment: I edited my post. It seems the method are called after the request ..

Comment: You should just receive multiple responses for a redirect

Comment: look my edit. It works if I wait it's finished. But is it a good way ? ( a while here, the performance .. )

Comment: You have no other option than to wait. Though if you know about the redirection why aren't you directly calling that URL?

Comment: That's say ? Otherwise, it is better to implement the solution of @Anil Santo ?

Comment: That is just a different API to do the same thing (with less options available), there will be no speed difference

Comment: Ok so actually, you think it's ok, it's an "acceptable code" with this while loop ?

Comment: Wait, no, I didn't see that edit. You should not loop like that. That indicates you're starting the connection on a background thread? You should start it only on the main thread

Comment: I think I didn't post the good code. This is the new/last . Tell me about please.
But the use of a while the request didn't finish it seems a little gross, because normally it does it automatically as a asynchronous request.

Comment: p.s. Welcome to stack overflow. Please vote for answers that helped and tick answers that solve your problem :-)

Comment: @Wain thanks you so much. I never thought about past my code in the connectionDidFinishLoading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is ill conceived:

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

while(!self.finished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

NSArray *last_name = [[self.myDictionnaryData objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"lastname"];
```

Because once you start the connection you should not be waiting for the response is a loop. The response is asynchronous so you should use it when it becomes available in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. Move all of your handling code to there (or, better, to a method called from there).

---

*Other issues:*

You shouldn't be doing this:

```
_myDictionnaryData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

(because you will never use that instance before it is replaced). And don't just move it to your `init` method as that has the same issue. And in your `init` method you need to call `super` before you try to set and instance variable content.

or this:

```
[*parseError release];
```

(because the error isn't yours to release).

Other than that your code is fine. This is asynchronous by its nature because it's using delegate methods, and the top level documentation for `NSURLConnection` describes how it is an asynchronous operation.

`didFailWithError:` will be called with any error related to the URL connection handling / server response.

Answer (score 1):

For Asynchronous Request you can use.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:url_string]]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
     NSString *returnString1  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnString1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];}];
```

Comment: NSURLConnection delegate is also asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I use OHURLLoader, ist depends on NSURLConnection, and is easy to use.

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHURLLoader

Comment: I don't want to use a library or file of someone. I want to implement it myself